# Can things move in an oblique motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Using common sense I know that things move in three dimensions x, y and z. Now, if a thing is moving along x and y at the same time we say that is moving in a oblique direction. Now, I want to know if this is actually what happens at a microscopic scale, I mean does matter really moves along x and y at the same time in continuous motion or do things move along an x direction first and then along a y direction? To make it more clear, does matter moves like going up the stairs or going up on an inclined plane.

EDIT: this doubt partially was born in my mind because of the concept of the Planck length, which should be the smallest distance possible. If that's true than a continuous motion of matter can't exist.

Comment: Ask yourself whether matter "knows" which directions you have chosen as x, y, and z.

Answer (score 1):

I like your question because you are trying to "zoom in" with your imagination and understand what things mean.  But try thinking of the motion without an x, y, and z frame of reference.  Would it be smooth?   The Cartesian coordinate system you're talking about was only invented to help us describe the position and motion of things, it does not affect or control the motion of things.